# I want to populate Last Record of child Due Date value in Parent Record Due Date Field value & I am getting error after insert record Read Only

Tags: apex, trigger

In this trigger I am Getting After insert record Read only in this Condition,

```
if(i == MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c){<br/>
    MapInvoice.get(invId).Due_Date__c = invl.Due_Date__c;<br/>
       }
```

---

```
trigger CreateInvoice on Invoice__c(after insert,after update){

    system.debug('********Starting Line*****');
    //Creating Empty instance for Invoice Line Item

    list<Invoice_Line_Item__c> listInvoice = new list<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();

    system.debug('listInvoice'+listInvoice);
    //Creating new map Instance for Invoices

    Map<id,Invoice__c> MapInvoice=new Map<id,Invoice__c>();

    system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
    //Iterating Loop to get the Invoice Records
    for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New){
        system.debug('invloop'+inv);
        MapInvoice.put(inv.id, inv);
        system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
    }
    //checking the size & Value
    If(MapInvoice.size()>0 && MapInvoice!=null){
        for(Id invId:MapInvoice.Keyset()){
            system.debug('****invId**** '+invId);
            DateTime invoiceDate = MapInvoice.get(invId).InvoiceDate__c;
            for(integer i=1;i<=MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c;i++){
                system.debug('***MapInvoice.get(invId)*****'+MapInvoice.get(invId));
                system.debug('***MapInvoice.get(invId)*****'+MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c);
                Integer count = 1;
                count = count * i;
                Invoice_Line_Item__c invl = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
                invl.Invoice__c = invId;
                invl.Name = MapInvoice.get(invId).Name +'- '+ i;
                invl.Price__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Price__c * count;
                invl.Quantity__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c * count;
                system.debug('=MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c==> '+MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c);
                system.debug('=MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c==> '+MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c * count);
                invl.Discount__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Discount__c;
                invl.Invoice_Date__c = invoiceDate;
                invl.Due_Date__c = invoiceDate.addDays(integer.valueOf(MapInvoice.get(invId).Net_Invoice__c));
                invoiceDate = invoiceDate.addDays(integer.valueOf(MapInvoice.get(invId).Net_Invoice__c));
               system.debug('=====>'+MapInvoice.get(invId).Due_Date__c);
                if(i == MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c){
                MapInvoice.get(invId).Due_Date__c = invl.Due_Date__c;
                }
                listInvoice.add(invl);
                system.debug('invl '+invl);
                system.debug('======'+MapInvoice.get(invId).Price__c * count);
            }    
        }
    }
    If(listInvoice.size()>0 && listInvoice!=null)
        insert listInvoice;
    system.debug('***'+listInvoice);
    system.debug('*****End of the line*****');
}
```

Comment: Please do not delete and repost your questions. Instead, edit your existing post to make improvements as requested by the community. Your posts should always include _all_ of the error details, in the body of the post: the verbatim text of the error and exactly where it is located (i.e., which line throws the error).

Comment: Ok David, I am getting After insert record read only in this condition 

if(i == MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c){

MapInvoice.get(invId).Due_Date__c = invl.Due_Date__c;
   }
 here what can i do please help me in this problem

Comment: Please **do not post comments to add information**. [Edit] this post to put the details **in the question body**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

trigger CreateInvoice on Invoice__c(after insert){

```
system.debug('********Starting Line*****');
//Creating Empty instance for Invoice Line Item

list<Invoice_Line_Item__c> listInvoice = new list<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();

system.debug('listInvoice'+listInvoice);
//Creating new map Instance for Invoices

Map<id,Invoice__c> MapInvoice=new Map<id,Invoice__c>();

system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
//Iterating Loop to get the Invoice Records
for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New){
    system.debug('invloop'+inv);
    MapInvoice.put(inv.id, inv);
    system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
}
//checking the size & Value
If(MapInvoice.size()>0 && MapInvoice!=null){
    for(Id invId:MapInvoice.Keyset()){
        system.debug('****invId**** '+invId);
        DateTime invoiceDate = MapInvoice.get(invId).InvoiceDate__c;
        for(integer i=1;i<=MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c;i++){
            system.debug('***MapInvoice.get(invId)*****'+MapInvoice.get(invId));
            system.debug('***MapInvoice.get(invId)*****'+MapInvoice.get(invId).Line_Count__c);
            Integer count = 1;
            count = count * i;
            Invoice_Line_Item__c invl = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();
            invl.Invoice__c = invId;
            invl.Name = MapInvoice.get(invId).Name +'- '+ i;
            invl.Price__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Price__c * count;
            invl.Quantity__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c * count;
            system.debug('=MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c==> '+MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c);
            system.debug('=MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c==> '+MapInvoice.get(invId).Quantity__c * count);
            invl.Discount__c = MapInvoice.get(invId).Discount__c;
            invl.Invoice_Date__c = invoiceDate;
            invl.Due_Date__c = invoiceDate.addDays(integer.valueOf(MapInvoice.get(invId).Net_Invoice__c));
            invoiceDate = invoiceDate.addDays(integer.valueOf(MapInvoice.get(invId).Net_Invoice__c));
            listInvoice.add(invl);
            system.debug('invl '+invl);
        }    
    }
}
If(listInvoice.size()>0 && listInvoice!=null)
    insert listInvoice;
system.debug('***'+listInvoice);
system.debug('*****End of the line*****');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't mutate the records in the trigger context variables during the `after` events, which is what you're doing here:

```
MapInvoice.get(invId).Due_Date__c = invl.Due_Date__c;
```

Instead, you need to construct *new* instances of the sObjects and populate the fields you wish to update. This will cause recursion of the trigger, which you need to be prepared to handle. (*Don't* use a static Boolean; search SFSE for lots of discussion about what that pattern doesn't work). For example, you'd have a `Map<Id, Invoice__c> invoicesToUpdate` and do `invoicesToUpdate.put(invId, new Invoice__c(Id = invId, Due_Date__c = invl.Due_Date__c);`. At the end of the trigger, you'd do `update invoicesToUpdate.values()`.

You can remove all of this code:

```
Map<id,Invoice__c> MapInvoice=new Map<id,Invoice__c>();

system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
//Iterating Loop to get the Invoice Records
for(Invoice__c inv:Trigger.New){
    system.debug('invloop'+inv);
    MapInvoice.put(inv.id, inv);
    system.debug('MapInvoice'+ MapInvoice);
}
//checking the size & Value
If(MapInvoice.size()>0 && MapInvoice!=null){
```

because what you're doing is recreating the built-in trigger context variable `Trigger.newMap`. You should reference that context variable everywhere you use `MapInvoice`.

Note also that you do not need to check whether this variable is null or empty. Triggers don't get invoked with empty context variables, and Apex collections are never initialized as `null`.

Comment: Please Answer about this Question

Comment: Please do not try to edit new questions into my answer post. That is not how Salesforce Stack Exchange works. Your new code has several syntax errors and other issues. You need to be using the `invoicesToUpdate` Map only to store instances that contain changes. It does not replace `Trigger.newMap`.